# jQuery Ajax call: Access to reference element in non closure

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the code I am using for making an ajax call

I want to know if there is a way to access the target element. A declared element target doesn't work maybe because I am defining the function handler outside of the event handler for click

How do I access target

```
function handleFavorite(data) {
    if (data.status) {
        var notification = noty({
            text: "Successfully added to favorite",
            type: "success"
        });
    } else {
        var notification = noty({
            text: data.error,
            type: "error"
        });

    }
    target.toggleClass("btn-danger").toggleClass("add").toggleClass("delete");
}

function toggleFavorite() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this);

    $.get(href, handleFavorite, "json");
    return false;
}

$(".favorite").click(toggleFavorite);
```

After some more thought into this, i think this would be the best way of going about it: To return the handler function by a function that accepts the element as parameter:

```
function createHandler($element){
    var target=$element;
    return function(data){
        if (data.status) {
          var notification = noty({
             text: "Successfully added to favorite",
             type: "success"
         });
         } else {
            var notification = noty({
            text: data.error,
            type: "error"
          });

     } 
    target.toggleClass("btn-danger").toggleClass("add").toggleClass("delete");
 }

}
//And in the ajax call
function toggleFavorite() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this);

    $.get(href, createHandler($(this)), "json");
    return false;
}

$(".favorite").click(toggleFavorite);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to solve it is to pass the variable as a parameter

```
function handleFavorite(target, data) {
    if (data.status) {
        var notification = noty({
            text: "Successfully added to favorite",
            type: "success"
        });
    } else {
        var notification = noty({
            text: data.error,
            type: "error"
        });

    }
    target.toggleClass("btn-danger").toggleClass("add").toggleClass("delete");
}

function toggleFavorite() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this);

    $.get(href, function(){
        handleFavorite(target, data)
    }, "json");
    return false;
}

$(".favorite").click(toggleFavorite);
```

Comment: sorry was thinking something else. This is actually the method I ended up using. I was wondering if there's a cleaner way of passing this.